# Why does the python decorator function nest a function?

Tags: python

```
def log(func):
     def wrapper(*args, **kw):
         print('call %s():' % func.__name__) 
         return func(*args, **kw)
     return wrapper
@log
def now():
     print('2017-5')
```

Why in the middle to nest wrapper function, why not?It's my first questions in stackoverflow and I'm not good at English .so my description hava any problem ,please forgive me .Thanks!!!

```
def log(func):
    print('call %s():' % func.__name__)
    return func(*args, **kw)
@log
def now():
    print('2017-5')
```

Comment: Did you try the second option? What did you see? That will answer your question.

Comment: If delete the (*args,**kw),It can runing right .But the function log can't get the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

A bit about decorators:

```
@decorator
def func():
    ...
```

exactly equals to:

```
func = decorator(func)
```

As you can notice, in the first option `print('call %s():' % func.__name__)` will be called any time when your function `now` is called in your program. In the second option, this `print` will be called when decorator applies only without calling `now`.

Nested function is used because decorator replaces the original function with the modified one.